# Best practices for managing Stellar accounts as an anchor

Tags: wallets, anchor

I'm building an anchor and instead of keeping a single account and use federation + memo, I'm sending my asset to each customer Stellar account. Today each user is managing their Stellar account and they are responsible for securing their seed.

I'd like to move to a model where each user don't have to worry about managing their accounts, my service will do it for them.

Under this model, each Stellar account will be holding my custom asset and it will have just enough XLM for minimum balance and sending payments with my custom asset.

Comment: Related https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/778/storing-secret-key-for-smart-contracts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not clear what you want to do. As far I understand the questions is *how users can hold my custom asset **and** XLM on the same account*. In that case, here's one way how to do that

- You already do auth_required and auth_revocable, let's keep that.
- whenever a user signs up to you, create account and setup trusts for him as before.
- on top of that, change their signer to your own "Client support" seed. In this case, user doesn't necessary is aware of Stellar and you don't have to juggle thousands of seeds yourself.
- whenever user wishes to "upgrade", ask him to generate a seed and change the signer of user account to user's seed. Now, user can use his account directly, including to hold XLM and other assets on it. Whenever he misbehaves, you have your auth_revocable flag.

Unfortunately some (idk, maybe all?) Stellar wallets do not support mismatching accountId and seed pairs yet. But stellar SDKs do, so it should come to wallets whenever a need arises.